# VHDL: Initialise rest of 2D array to zero

Tags: arrays, initialization, vhdl

I currently have this array, which has some data at the beginning and then the rest are zero. I tried to use the "others" command, but it didn't work.

```
    type data_type is array (0 to n-1) of std_logic_vector(len downto 0); 
    constant data: data_type:=(                     
                                    "00000001",
                                    "00000011",
                                    "00001001",
                                    "00001011",
                                    "00001111",
                                    "00000000",
                                    "00000000",
                                    "00000000"
                                    );
```

My attempt:

```
    type data_type is array (0 to n-1) of std_logic_vector(len downto 0); 
    constant data: data_type:=(                     
                                    "00000001",
                                    "00000011",
                                    "00001001",
                                    "00001011",
                                    "00001111",
                                    (others=> (others=>'0'))
                                    );
--
```

I received the following error:

```
Type of aggregate cannot be determined without context ; 0 visible types match here
```

Comment: `(others=> (others=>'0'))` is a complete new aggregate. `others=> (others=>'0')` is an others clause in the current aggregate.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked!! Brackets were the issue then

Comment: You can post the answer if you want